# jQuery sortable (how to customize the clickable area inside the sortable box)

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(".right_box_holder").sortable({ 
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('.right_box_holder').sortable('serialize'); 
            $.get("right_menu_functions.php?change_sortorder&"+order);
        }   
    });
```

and this HTML code:

```
<div class='right_box_holder'>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_0'>
    // sort box 0
  </div>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_1'>
    // sort box 1
  </div>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_2'>
    // sort box 2
  </div>
</div>
```

As it is now, I can click anywhere inside .right_box and move it. I want to disable this and make a button / icon inside .right_box which the user have to click on to drag the box. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iwufe4/edit

Use the handle method

```
$(".right_box_holder").sortable({ 
        handle: '.button_icon_or_css_sprite', // use the handle method
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('.right_box_holder').sortable('serialize'); 
            $.get("right_menu_functions.php?change_sortorder&"+order);
        }   
    });

<div class='right_box_holder'>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_0'>
    <img class="button_icon_or_css_sprite" />
  </div>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_1'>
    <img class="button_icon_or_css_sprite" />
  </div>
  <div class='right_box' id='box_2'>
   <img class="button_icon_or_css_sprite" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a feature of Draggable - used by sortable.

Have a look at [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle). Good luck!